# In java, when to use StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase vs. equalsIgnoreCase?

Tags: java, equals, contains

I'm doing some coding in java and I'm curious as to when to use StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase vs. equalsIgnoreCase? When is it more appropriate to use one over the other? What is actually the big difference? Thanks guys...any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you know what contains means? Do you know what equals means? Then you should be able to answer this yourself without anything more than the method names.

Comment: This question is fundamentally the same as asking "When is it more appropriate to use `>=` over `>`? What is actually the big difference?"

Answer (score 7):

If you read the [specs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), you see that 
[`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) checks if a String contains another String while [`StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) checks if two Strings are equal.

Comment: Using StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase will still return true if both strings are equal. However, it will be much more inefficient because it will use a string matching algorithm instead of a simple comparison of each character.

Comment: Given the self-evident names of the methods, you hardly even need to check their specs :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the following Strings:

```
String a = "ABCdefGHIjkl";
String b = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
String c = "ABCd";
```

Then `a` contains `c`, but is not equal to `c`. `a` contains `b` *and* is equal to `b`. (Here where I say "equals", I mean "equalsIgnoreCase"; same for contains.)

You'd use one or the other depending on whether you'd want partial matches to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase`: checks whether a particular String contains another String.

For example:

```
StringUtils.contains(null, *) = false
StringUtils.contains("abc", "") = true
```

`equalsIgnoreCase`: Checks if two Strings are the same.

For example:

```
"Test".equalsIgnoreCase("Test") = true
"Test".equalsIgnoreCase("T") = false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase
```

is from Apache Commons.
It checks for whether the string contains a search string.

```
 StringUtils.contains(null, *) = false
 StringUtils.contains(*, null) = false
 StringUtils.contains("", "") = true
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "") = true
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "a") = true
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "z") = false
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "A") = true
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "Z") = false
```

API docs for both methods: [equalsIgnoreCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [containsIgnoreCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)